Type T and any in Vue 3 with typescript
I have this code for Tile component in Vue 3.4 with typescript
 <template>
  <FormControl :valid="isValid">
    <template v-if="props.inlineContent">
      <input
        :id="name"
        v-model="checked"
        :name
        class="ods__form__check ods__form__check--btn"
        type="checkbox"
      />
      <label
        :for="name"
        class="ods__form__label ods__pos-relative"
      >
      </label>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <div
        :aria-checked="checked"
        class="ods__form__selectcard"
        role="checkbox"
        tabindex="0"
        data-toggle="select-card"
        @click="toggleModelValue"
        @keydown.space.prevent="toggleModelValue"
      >
        <TileCardContent
          :label
        >
        </TileCardContent>
      </div>
    </template>
    <ErrorMessage :id="errorMessagesId" :errors></ErrorMessage>
  </FormControl>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import ErrorMessage from '@/components/display/ErrorMessage.vue'
import FormControl from '@/components/layout/FormControl.vue'
import { computed, type VNode } from 'vue'
import useInput from '@/composable/common/use-input'
import TileCardContent from '@/components/common/tile/TileCardContent.vue'

interface Props {
  /** Définit le nom (unique) de la tile */
  name: string
  /** Définit le label de la tile */
  label?: string
  /** Propriété qui indique si la tile doit passer en mode inline (change la disposition des éléments textes) */
  inlineContent?: boolean
  /** item : Propriété de type Any qui contient la valeur de la tile */
  item: any 
}
const props = defineProps<Props>()

defineModel<any[]>({ required: true })
const { errors, value, isValid, errorMessagesId } = useInput<any[]>(props.name)

const checked = computed({
  get() {
    return value.value ? value.value.some(item => item.key === props.item.key) : false;
  },
  set(checked: boolean) {
    if (value.value === undefined) {
      value.value = []; 
    }
    if (checked) {
      value.value.push(props.item);
    } else {
      value.value = value.value.filter(item => item.key !== props.item.key);
    }
  }
});

function toggleModelValue() {
  checked.value = !checked.value
}
</script>

and this code for story with storybook
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/vue3'
import Tile from './Tile.vue'
import * as yup from 'yup'
import {  useField } from 'vee-validate'
import { ref, watch, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { withCodeSnippet } from '../../../../.storybook/decorator'

const meta: Meta<typeof Tile> = {
  component: Tile,

}

export default meta
type Story = StoryObj<typeof Tile>

type Appliance = {
  key: string
  coefficient: number
}
export const Default: Story = {
  name: 'With validation',
  render: (args) => ({
    components: { Tile },
    setup() {
      const appliances: Appliance[] = [
        { key: 'appliance1', coefficient: 10 },
        { key: 'appliance2', coefficient: 20 },
        { key: 'appliance3', coefficient: 30 },
        { key: 'appliance4', coefficient: 40 },
        { key: 'appliance5', coefficient: 50 }
      ]

      const modelValue = ref<Appliance[]>([])

      const { errors, value, validate } = useField<Appliance[]>(
        'appliances',
        yup
          .array()
          .of(
            yup.object().shape({
              key: yup.string().required(),
              coefficient: yup.number().required()
            })
          )
          .required()
          .min(1)
      )
      watch(
        modelValue,
        (newValue) => {
          value.value = newValue
          validate()
        },
        { deep: true }
      )
      onMounted(async () => {
        await validate()
      })

      return {
        appliances,
        modelValue,
        errors,
        value
      }
    },
    template: `
    <div class="ods__d-grid ods__gap ods__g-cols-2">      
      <div v-for="appliance in appliances" :key="appliance.key">
        <Tile 
          v-model="modelValue" 
          :item="appliance" 
          :label="appliance.key" 
          :name="appliance.key"
        />
      </div>
    </div> 
    <p v-if="errors">Errors: {{ errors }}</p> 
    <p>Selected Appliances: {{ modelValue }}</p>
  `
  })
}


I was asked to change the type of prop item from any to Generic type T, so I updated this lines
<script generic="T" lang="ts" setup>
...
interface Props {
...
  item: T 
}
...
defineModel<T[]>({ required: true })
const { errors, value, isValid, errorMessagesId } = useInput<T[]>(props.name)

I got this error with item.key

"Property 'key' does not exist on type 'T'.ts-plugin(2339) any"

after looking for solution I updated this line
<script generic="T extends { key: any }"  lang="ts" setup>

Then I get an error with the story telling

Type '<T extends { key: any; }>(__VLS_props: { "onClick-infobutton"?:
(() => any) | undefined; "onUpdate:modelValue"?: ((modelValue: T[]) =>
any) | undefined; modelValue: T[]; name: string; label?: string |
undefined; ... 10 more ...; item: T; } & VNodeProps &
AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps, __VLS_ctx?: { .....' has
no properties in common with type 'Omit<ConcreteComponent,
"props">'.ts(2559) index.d.ts(408, 5): The expected type comes from
property 'component' which is declared here on type 'Meta<(<T extends
{ key: any; }>(__VLS_props: { "onClick-infobutton"?: (() => any) |
undefined; "onUpdate:modelValue"?: ((modelValue: T[]) => any) |
undefined; modelValue: T[]; name: string; label?: string | undefined;
... 10 more ...; item: T; } & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps &
ComponentCustomProps, __VLS_ctx?...' (property)
ComponentAnnotations<VueRenderer, <T extends { key: any;
}>(__VLS_props: NonNullable<Awaited>["props"],
__VLS_ctx?: { attrs: any; emit: Events & ((evt: "update:modelValue", modelValue: T[]) => void); slots: ReturnType<() => Readonly<...> &
Slots>; }, __VLS_expose?: NonNullable<Awaited>["expose"], __VLS_setup?: Promise<...>) => VNode<...> & { ...; }>.component?: Omit<ConcreteComponent, "props"> | undefined
The primary component for your story.
Used by addons for automatic prop table generation and display of
other component metadata.

How can I fix this error, with keeping my component generic and reusable (so I can pass any item like appliances) ?

Have you tried out const meta: Meta<typeof Tile> = {component: Tile<Appliance>,}

@BoussadjraBrahim yes but didn't works

Try to make a minimal reproduction as github repo/ slackblitz in order to debug it

@BoussadjraBrahim the error was related to a bug in storybook (https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/24238) , I fixed it with this line  type GenericTile= Record<keyof typeof Tile, VNode>
const meta: Meta = { component: Tile as GenericTile }

Great, try to post the solution as answer

The error was related to a bug in storybook.
I fixed it by adding this code
 type GenericTile= Record<keyof typeof Tile, VNode> 
 const meta: Meta<typeof Tile> = { component: Tile as GenericTile }


